# Effect on updating current running WAR file in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

What would happen on the current running application if you are going to update the WAR file in Google App Engine? Will Google App Engine automatically stop the service of your application while new WAR file is being uploaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying a new version of your app causes App Engine to spin up an entirely new set of VMs with your new code, transfer traffic from the old VMs to the new ones, then shutdown the old ones (presuming you're deploying to the default version). At no point is your service down - traffic transitions seamlessly from the old instance to the new one.

Comment: hi nick,
at the time when Google transfers your app to the new VMs, what happens to the currently processing requests from the old VMs? My guess is that it finish all transactions from the old one before shutting it down, and all new transactions will be processed in the new ones?

Is there any document with this one from Google?

Comment: Correct - the old VMs are kept running until all current requests have finished processing.